# "-k" option for "ls -l" commnad

Tags: 14.04, ls

I can not use "-k" option for `ls -l` commnad.

```
   -k, --kibibytes
          use 1024-byte blocks
```

There is an option explanation in `man ls` like above.
So I guess that this option is valid.
However, there is no difference of output between `ls -l` and `ls -lk`.
Could anyone teach me how to validate "-k" option?

Comment: Thank you Foerster-san. I use "--block-size=K" instead of "-k" which is not valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Older versions of `ls(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/ls.1.html) have a different description of the `-k` option, which I find more accurate:

> ```
> -k     like --block-size=1K
>
> --block-size=SIZE
>           scale   sizes   by   SIZE   before   printing    them.     E.g.,
>           `--block-size=M'  prints sizes in units of 1,048,576 bytes.  See
>           SIZE format below.
> ```

That means `-k` will lead to `ls` displaying all file sizes divided by 1024. This may be overridden by other (implicit) options like `-h` (which displays file sizes “human readable”, i. e. scaled depending on their size and with a scale suffix (K, M, G, T, …)).

You can determine, whether `ls` is an alias with default command line arguments with `alias ls`. You can circumvent the alias and run the command directly with `command ls -l`.

Comment: Is there a straightforward one-liner to just accomplish kibibyte sized output with `ls` with latest version Ubuntu?

Comment: That would still be `-k` [according to the manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/ls.1.html). As I understand it, only the description of that option has changed since Precise.